# Ordinary Differential Equation or Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I formulate a dynamic system using the following differential equation:
$\frac{dX}{dt}=f(X(t), Y(t), Z(t))$, where $X\in \mathbb{R}$ evolves according to the differential equation. The dynamics of $Y, Z \in \mathbb{R}$ are known. And we know $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I have two questions:

1. Is this an ODE or PDE? I think it is a PDE because it involves three independent variables $X,Y,Z$.
2. How we can numerically solve it? Which python function can solve it?

Comment: ODEs are technically PDEs, and this is an ODE.

Comment: $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are not the independent variables. They are dependent variables (functions of $t$).  $t$ is the independent variable, and there's only one, so it's an ODE.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So it is an ODE. Which python function can solve it? I found most of the python function can only solve $\frac{dX}{dt}=f(X(t))$.

Comment: Since you know $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$, your equation is non-autonomous, of the form $\frac{dX}{dt}=f(X,t)$. You can make it autonomous and solve it using your Python function by considering $t$ part of your dependent variable, that is $W=(X,t)$ and introducing a new "time" $s$ with $\frac{dt}{ds}=1$.

Comment: @GReyes Can you specify the ODE with the new time $s$?

Comment: Yes. Now you have a system for $X,t$: $\frac{dX}{ds}=f(X,t)$ and $\frac{dt}{ds}=1$, or, in terms of $W$: $\frac{dW}{ds}=F(W):=(f(W),1)$. Every non-autonomous system can be made autonomous with this trick. Motion is an illusion, as Parmenides would say..:-)

Comment: @GReyes How to deal with $Y$ and $Z$?

Comment: You mentioned that you know $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$, so you just plug them into $f$ to get $\tilde f(X,t)=f(X,Y(t),Z(t))$. This $\tilde f$ is the one that will appear on the right hand side of your system.

Comment: @GReyes Thank you so much!